# Store vectors with different length as a list in R

Tags: arrays, r, list, loops, matrix

For the code below, I want to store the `(a*b)` for each edge in a vector `op1` and after that to store all vectors in a list `opp1`. According to the given data: I should have 5 vectors `op1`each one with a different length (for example: `length(op1[1]=3)` while the rest of vectors of length `2` like `length(op1[2]=2)`) and I will have one list `opp1` contain the vectors of different lengths.

Storing the values in the vectors is OK but my problem is when storing these vectors, the resulted list contain the vectors but with the same length, i.e `opp1`list consist of all `op1` vectors with length 3 so there is a strange value added from no where.

```
library(igraph)
graph<-matrix(c(4,3,4,1,4,2,3,2,3,1),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
g<-graph.data.frame(d = graph, directed = FALSE)
v1<-c()
v2<-c()
n1<-list()
n2<-list()
op1<-c()
opp1<-list()
for (edge in 1:length(E(g))){
  v1[edge] <- ends(graph = g, es = edge)[1]
  v2[edge] <- ends(graph = g, es = edge)[2]
  n1[[edge]] <- names(neighbors(g, v1[edge], mode = "all"))
  n2[[edge]] <- names(neighbors(g, v2[edge], mode = "all"))
for (neighbor in 1:length(n2[[edge]])){
a<-as.numeric(v2[edge])
b<-as.numeric(n2[[edge]][neighbor])
c<-(a*b)
op1[neighbor]<-c
}
opp1[[edge]]<-op1
}
```

The list `opp1` is:

```
 opp1
[[1]]
[1] 12  3  6

[[2]]
[1] 4 3 6

[[3]]
[1] 8 6 6

[[4]]
[1] 8 6 6

[[5]]
[1] 4 3 6
```

while it should be:

```
 opp1
[[1]]
[1] 12  3  6

[[2]]
[1] 4 3 

[[3]]
[1] 8 6 

[[4]]
[1] 8 6

[[5]]
[1] 4 3
```

Is there any advice how to fix the code, also is there another way to do the same work in a different way especially to save time and memory when working on big data.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize `op1` inside the first for loop in the way to have a clean `op1` in each cycle, like this:

```
 for (edge in 1:length(E(g))){
   op1<-c()
   v1[edge] <- ends(graph = g, es = edge)[1]
   v2[edge] <- ends(graph = g, es = edge)[2]
   n1[[edge]] <- names(neighbors(g, v1[edge], mode = "all"))
   n2[[edge]] <- names(neighbors(g, v2[edge], mode = "all"))
   for (neighbor in 1:length(n2[[edge]])){
     a<-as.numeric(v2[edge])
     b<-as.numeric(n2[[edge]][neighbor])
     c<-(a*b)
     op1[neighbor]<-c
   }
   opp1[[edge]]<-op1

 }
```

Your output:

```
opp1
[[1]]
[1] 12  3  6

[[2]]
[1] 4 3

[[3]]
[1] 8 6

[[4]]
[1] 8 6

[[5]]
[1] 4 3
```

Without for loop is better and faster:

```
 n<-length(E(g))

 v1x<-unlist(lapply(lapply(c(1:n),ends,graph=g),"[[",1))
 v2x<-unlist(lapply(lapply(c(1:n),ends,graph=g),"[[",2))

 n1x<-lapply(lapply(v1x,neighbors,graph=g,mode="all"),names)
 b<-Map(as.numeric,lapply(lapply(v2x,neighbors,graph=g,mode="all"),names))

 a<-mapply(rep, as.numeric(v2x), lapply(n2x,length))

 opp1<-Map('*',a,b)
opp1
[[1]]
[1] 12  3  6

[[2]]
[1] 4 3

[[3]]
[1] 8 6

[[4]]
[1] 8 6

[[5]]
[1] 4 3
```

Comment: Terror Thanks for help. Do you suggest another efficient way (if exist) instead of this loop? because I need to iterate it many times and for huge data..

Comment: Done in the answer.